# Water heater T&P valve always draining

Tags: water, heater

Nothing in our system has changed. Now all of a sudden the valve opens and allows water to drain. It fills a gallon bucket twice a day. I replaced the T&P valve and still leaks. Temp is set at 120 degrees and water out of the faucet is 120. What causes this?

Comment: Where does it leak?  From the valve or the threads?

Comment: I guess leaking is a bad term. Nothing is leaking but the valve keeps opening to allow water to flow

Comment: So this is a tank water heater, right? Is there a check valve to prevent backflow of water from your plumbing into the water mains? Do you have a pressure reducer to lower the pressure in your house plumbing from a higher pressure in the city mains? Do you know what the pressure is in your house plumbing? The city water department may state on their website what pressure they supply waater at.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, if "nothing has changed" the invisible change is the bladder in your expansion tank failing, and you need a new one.

The expansion tank is to deal with excessive pressure when a lot of hot water is used, replaced by cold water, and heated,  which makes it expand, which causes the pressure to rise, sometimes (as seen here) beyond the pressure setting of the relief valve.

Blaming the relief valve is a common error.

Comment: I don’t have an expansion tank. System if 17 years old and nothing has been adjusted

Comment: Do you have a pressure reducer or back flow preventer on the cold line entering the house?

Comment: Ask the city water dept if they have increased the mains pressure or have had fluctuations in pressure.